# return statement in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have my JavaScript code as:

```
$('[id^="thresholdParameter_"]').each(function(i, value) {  

        //any field is edited
        if($(this).val() !== previousThresholdParameters[i]){
            alert('Hello');
            return true;
        }
    });
```

Here I want that once it reaches `return true;` it must come out of the function and return the true value. However, it it keeps on iterarting.

Why is it so? return in JavaScript does not function like return in Java??

Comment: Please make sure the condition is met and alert statement is executed.

Comment: Next time please read the [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/each/)...

Comment: I think you should use "return false;" instead of "return true;" to break the loop

Answer (score 3):

Return false in each callback will only stop the each function.

See last example from jQuery each API: http://api.jquery.com/each/

You can try this:

```
var conditionMet = false;

$(selector).each(function() {
  if (innerConditionMet) {
    conditionMet = true;
    return false; // stop the each
  }
});
```

Answer (score 3):

Use `return false` instead of `return true`, as `return true` treated as `continue` and `return false` as `break` in `$.each loop`,

```
$('[id^="thresholdParameter_"]').each(function(i, value) {  
    //any field is edited
    if($(this).val() !== previousThresholdParameters[i]){
        alert('Hello');
        return false; // use false
    }
});
```

From [$.each()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/)

> We can break the $.each() loop at a particular iteration by making the
>   callback function return false. Returning non-false is the same as a
>   continue statement in a for loop; it will skip immediately to the next
>   iteration.

Answer (score 1):

Try this since in your case it looks like you want to return `true` and used somewhere else:

```
var flag = false;
$('[id^="thresholdParameter_"]').each(function(i, value) {  
  //any field is edited
  if($(this).val() !== previousThresholdParameters[i]){
    alert('Hello');
    flag = true;
    return false;
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var x = $('[id^="thresholdParameter_"]');

for(i in x){

if(x[i] !== previousThresholdParameters[i]){

 alert('Hello');
 return true; //
 break;

 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

retun false to break out of $.each()

try this fiddle for better understanding: http://jsfiddle.net/patelmilanb1/q348g/

```
<div class="number">
     <h1>1</h1>

     <h1>2</h1>

     <h1>3</h1>

     <h1>4</h1>

     <h1>5</h1>

     <h1>6</h1>

     <h1>7</h1>

</div>

$('.number h1').each(function () {
    var h1Value = $(this).text();
    if (h1Value == 5) {
        return false;
    } else {
        $(this).css("background-color", "#F1F1EF");
    }
});
```

it will add background colour to all h1 untill it reaches number 5 and then breaks out of $.each loop